# PHP Front-End for Database Functionality Similar to File Permissions in Windows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, file-permissions

I'm trying to implement a table row permission system in my database (with a PHP front-end and MySQL back-end). It should follow the Windows File Permission system, in the sense that:

- There are users
- Each user can be a member of several groups
- Each group can be a member of other supergroups
- You can specify an entire group, supergroup or a single user for
  permissions
- Should be: User permission supercedes subgroup supercedes supergroup. *(<- not entirely necessary)*

The user, after creating the database entry, can specify which groups/users should have which permissions (read, write or leave invisible). When accessing the web front-end, only the entries which they have permissions on should be displayed (using a cookie login system). Only those which they have Write access to should be available for editing.

Basically, I don't know how to efficiently create the database to relate the user to the permissions they should have on the file (I know, once I get the permission 'level', how to do the rest of course).

I've tried relation tables, but that got complicated very fast. I tried arrays of User/Group IDs in the file entry itself (as a field for the file), but this was sloppy and only supported 64 entries (as well as being difficult to implement the group/user heirarchies).

Are there any examples, add-ins, anything to help with this? I'm versed in Javascript, PHP, SQL, HTML and their relationships and I'm re-writing an old version using the new PDO extension. I know it's in the realm of possibility, but every stratagy I've tried has just been a nightmare.

Comment: As bad as Security is in Windows, the file permissions do seem to work well (when they work properly..). My clients want to mimic that functionality.

Comment: Isn't this like LDAP? :?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would apply that to MySQL database. They are not real directories, they are rows in a table which need restricted access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using Oracle, you could use role functionality to deal with the hierarchy of groups.  Mysql doesnt currently offer this functionality (although it seems to be on a list to do [here](http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=988) ).

In the meantime, you could mimic this functionality something like this.
Create a table called roles which has id and name fields and populate with a set of roles.

[image]

Create a table called user_role_privs that will hold the direct links from users to a role.

[image]

and create a table called role_role_privs that holds roles that are granted other roles

[image]

Finally, we add a table that we want to only be accessed by certain privileges so we add the columns we want plus one for the role that can view this data.

[image]

and then we create a new view which uses the data in the role tables plus the current_user() function to determine what data can be displayed.

```
create or replace view user_student 
    as select s.id, s.name, s.age
        from user_role_privs urp, student s 
       where urp.user=current_user() 
         and urp.role=s.role
       union 
      select s.id, s.name, s.age
        from user_role_privs urp, role_role_privs rrp, student s
       where urp.user=current_user()
         and urp.role=rrp.role_id
         and rrp.granted_role=s.role
```

Now if your php allows user1 to login, they will select from the view and see the following data - that is Pluto is seen based on the direct role grant and Mickey and Donald because the role of clerk is granted to the role of Manager.

But if user2 logins,  They will only see the records directly granted to their role of Clerk which are Mickey and Donald.

So if your application selects data from the user_student role instead of the student table, it would provide read access.

To do write access based on the role, you would probably need to extend this idea to include an edit flag on the role table and only show an edit button and related functionality if the role permitted it.

A role should have access to edit any data it can see so you keep the code simpler by creating more roles if needed.  For inserts into the table, you may also need a before insert trigger, to insert a role of the user that created it in the student.role column.  You would have to decide if this should be the role with the highest or lowest privileges as this then grants other users access as well.

Comment: Very thorough, thank you. This is similar to how I had it set up previously, but it became very complicated very fast (mainly because they wanted an administrative screen to assign roles etc without using phpMyAdmin to edit the tables directly). I like this View stuff though, I didn't know about that. I'll look into it, maybe it will simplify things.

Comment: Sure - the intention here is to use as much built in functionality as possible. In oracle the role stuff is also built in so it would be even easier.  The link to mysql adding roles is a bit old and it was low priority so maybe it got dropped as a candidate but if they add that, with this approach you can then replace the role tables to use the base roles as well.

Comment: The part that makes my criteria hard is that there isn't just a couple of roles, there's closer to 100. The main thing I'm running into is that if an entry has read/write permissions to most (but not all) users, there's likely around 150 linked rows among those tables for one entry. When dealing with 100'000+ entries, I'm worried about the performance. If each user had one 'permission type' it would be easy, but they've requested several permission types (similar to the Windows File System permissions; user, group, subgroup, subsubgroup and so on..). The tables get messy.

Comment: In the latter case, maybe you could identify the roles as either inclusive or exclusive so in the view you would join where (role=granted_role and role=inclusive ) and not exists (role=granted_role and role=exclusive).  Haven't worked this through but idea is to change the real world model so it's easier to code - here using the smallest data set for exclusion rather than bigger one for inclusion.